# An unspecified error occurred. The App ID exists in the App Store so it cannot be removed in ios

Tags: ios, app-store, itunes

I am trying to delete the app ID in my account but it can't be deleted and I also got the error like 
**An unspecified error occurred.  The App ID  exists in the App Store so it cannot be removed** . I also checked in app store(itune store) but it was not there. How can i delete the app id in apple account? Please explain the way of procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is late to answer this questions, but it will help other newcomer.

You can delete only those app id for which you haven't created app on itunesconnect account.

Once if you have use app id to create application on itunesconnect account then you cannot delete that app id.

Answer (score -1):

App IDs are permanent. There is no way to delete an app ID once registered, and since app IDs are global, the same ID cannot be used even in a different account.

Comment: we can create as well as delete the app id in developer account(https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingProfiles/MaintainingProfiles.html)

Comment: We can delete app id. Just click on App ID on developer portal, click on edit and you can see delete button. (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingProfiles/MaintainingProfiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH30-SW52)